# How to generate different sitemap for public schema and rest of the tenants using the Django sitemap framework for a django_tenants project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-sitemaps, django-tenants

I am using `django_tenants` and I am planning to use [`Django sites framework`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) to create sitemap for each of the tenant and the public schema. But the public schema shall have a different sitemap since its apps are different than that of the tenants.

How to generate different sitemap for public schema and rest of the tenants using the Django sitemap framework?